# Migrating a small office away from an Active Domain setup

Tags: windows, active-directory, exchange-2007

I'm helping a small charity move away from an Active Domain setup. They will be using Google Apps and Dropbox to replace the main functionality and their new office will just have a router providing DHCP on a local subnet.

What steps should I take to to convert the accounts on each machine from Domain accounts to simple local user accounts? Or is that even the best thing to do?

I'm a Linux guy so not even sure if I am asking the right question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Active Domain?  You mean Active DIRECTORY?  I believe the User Profile Wizard from ForensIT can convert the profiles to local profiles (you're losing centralized management and logon by leaving the domain structure).  Or you could just use local accounts and copy the data from the old accounts (MAKE SURE you know the local administrator password before removing the machines from the domain).

Honestly, if they have a Windows server, I do not see the point in leaving it.  Use google apps and dropbox if you want.  But keep the server for centralized management and account database.

Comment: Active Directory? Cool, I'll get the there, like I said I normally manage Linux networks :) They are moving office and won't have any kind of server at the new location. So the important point seems to be to make sure there is a local admin account on each machine.